# Maintaining Session across async calls in Mule

Tags: mule, mule-component

I have a specific requirement wherein Mule would be pulling information from  provider system and sending it to other system, there are series of such asynchronous calls wherein we have to correlate each messages to a specific user session, can someone throw their insight as how can we maintain session in mule for asynchronous calls? One approach I thought to store it in the DB but it would cause an performance issue. Any thoughts would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Object Stores](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/mule-object-stores) for that, where each user session can be stored and accessed in the store by an unique id. They can be in-memory or physically persisted (depending on your requirements). Check the [Object Store Connector](https://mulesoft.github.io/objectstore-connector/) to easily get and store objects from the stores.

Comment: Thanks @Nuno for the response, is there any limitations on using the Object Store, what I got to know is that it cannot handle huge amount of data in it and has some upper limit?

Comment: If you are running your app in CloudHub, you have limitations. If you are running on-premises, I think the only limitation is your heap size. You can check [this](https://www.ricston.com/blog/mule-object-store-jdbc/) example to persist the object store into database (recomended for clustered environments). I am not sure (hope I am wrong), but objects in the store are kept in memory even if you use a persisted object store (however, if you restart your app, you keep your object alive). But you can check that performing some tests. Hope it helps.